# Autodisposing objects

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

For instance I have a method

```
SomeMethod(Graphics g)
{
    ...
}
```

If I will call this method in a manner

```
SomeMethod(new Graphics())
```

Will my graphics object be autodisposed or I should call `g.Dispose()`  manually in the end of the method?

```
SomeMethod(Graphics g)
{
    ...
    g.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: In addition to 'no', your method should also *not* be responsible for disposing the graphics object. It's important that the graphics objects lifetime be managed in a single place - meaning it should be disposed in the same class that created it. Having an object be disposed in some indeterminate place down the call stack makes the code hard to understand and maintain, and could easily lead to errors later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disposable objects will not get autodisposed (the closest they can get to that is implementing a Finalizer that calls `Dispose` if necessary). You have to do this manually by calling `Dispose()` or by using it with a `using` block.

If you want to auto dispose the object, you could do this:

```
using (var g = new Graphics()) {
    SomeMethod(g);
}
```

The using block ensures that the `Dispose()` method is called automatically as soon as the block ends (so in this case, after `SomeMethod` returns or throws an exception).

Note: You should dispose the object at the location near where you created it, if possible. Taking in a valid object and disposing of it inside the method could cause confusion.

Graphics and probably most if not all BCL classes implementing this interface will also call `Dispose()` when the Finalizer is called. This is part of a proper implementation of `IDisposable`. However you never know when the finalizer is called and you should not rely on this implementation detail if you need your object to be deterministically disposed of.

Comment: In my example above, will graphics object be autodisposed or not?

Comment: Wait, are you saying the GC wont call `Dispose` when the object is finalized? (Given a correct implementation of `IDisposable`)

Comment: That is not true. All objects that implement IDisposable WILL get disposed sooner or later even if you do not call Dispose on them. Finalizer/destructor should call Dispose to release unmanaged resources if you follow IDisposable pattern properly. Calling Dispose explicitly is just a strong hit for GC to dispose object sooner.

Comment: A correct implementation is not automatic and nothing that should be taken for granted. Also, why should Dispose be a strong hit for GC? If it's used for unmanaged resources, it's nothing that the GC could take care of anyway.

Comment: True that Dispose releases unmanaged resourced immediately but all managed, including `this`, are actually released by GC. That's why it's a hint rather than actual object release. Correct implementation is to make sure all unmanaged resources are released no matter what (i.e. you call Dispose or not). Destructor should call Dispose as a safety net. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx

Comment: The question was not about managed resources, which we all know are released by the GC. Also, the question was about **using** IDisposable objects, not implementing them. These are different things. When _implementing_ an IDisposable class, you should follow the recommended patterns. Users of your class might fail to dispose it, so this makes sense.  When _using_ an IDisposable object, you should always call Dispose(), because you cannot assume everyone implements IDisposable the recommended way. This makes sense, too.

Comment: You are correct that question was not about `IDisposable` implementation. That's why I am not commenting the question but your answer, specifically "Disposable objects will not get autodisposed." which is simply not true and should be corrected to not mislead others.

Comment: It is true. IDisposable.Dispose() is not called automatically. Only the Finalizer is (if you create one).

Comment: For every disposable object in .NET library and for all other properly coded classes this is not true.

Comment: That's implementation specific. It **doesn't apply to all disposable objects** and you shouldn't use that as a reason not to properly dispose of the object. Even if Dispose is called in the finalizer, you never know when that finalizer will run. IDisposable is an interface, and that interface doesn't make any guarantees about automatically calling Dispose.

Comment: You are generalizing and the guy talks about `Graphics` which follows proper `IDisposable` pattern. In this context it is wrong to say that disposable objects will not autodispose. All framework object will do that. Don't you see how misleading this is? And I am not saying to not manually dispose - you surely should.

Comment: Graphics does follow that pattern. Still, the IDisposable interface alone does not make that guarantee, nor does the runtime.

Comment: No guarantees from `IDisposable` or runtime. Still, ALL framework objects do that. Ok, let's leave it.

Comment: @MaciejDopieralski Finalizers in .net are not guaranteed to run! Never rely on them for disposing unmanaged resources!

Comment: @ach Read carefully, I am not relying on them, although they are the last chance to free unmanaged resource.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to work with disposable objects is to wrap them in `using` blocks:

```
using (var g = new Graphics()) {
  SomeMethod(g);
}
```

When execution leaves the `using` block the `Graphics` is properly disposed even if an exception is thrown.

However, if you don't dispose the object either explicitely or implicitely using a `using` block the object **will still get disposed** when it is garbage collected (assuming that the finalizer correctly calls the `Dispose` as it should). When that happens is not within your control and that is why you should make sure that disposable objects are properly disposed as soon as they no longer are needed to free resources claimed by the objects.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use a using statement

```
using (var graphicsObject = new Graphics()) {
    SomeMethod(graphicsObject);
}
```

The object will automatically be disposed at the end of the using statement, even if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Graphics Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx)

```
public sealed class Graphics : MarshalByRefObject, 
    IDeviceContext, IDisposable
```

It implements the `IDisposable` interface, so if you use the `using` statement with the Graphics object then it will automatically disposed.

In your example

```
SomeMethod(Graphics g)
        {
        ...
        g.Dispose();
        }
```

it will be disposed using the `g.Dispose`, but best practice is `using` statement.

example:

```
using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
{
//Do some graphics operation.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example you should not dispose an object given to you as an argument. This is not advisable because that object could be used outside your method. Disposal of utility objects should (usually) take place in the same method you create it. Exception for class wide objects or state objects.

As in other answers, use `using` to create and dispose an object. This is only really required on objects that use some valuable resources like database connection. Having said that you should always call `Dispose()` (explicitly or by `using`) if the object implements it because that means it uses unmanaged or big amounts of resources.

All .NET Framework objects that you do not call `Dispose` on (either way) **will eventually get autodisposed** by Garbage Collector. Proper implementation of `IDisposable` interface should have destructor/finalizer that calls `Dispose`. This is to make sure valuable resources are not lost just because of bad code. Your resources would be released much later but they would and that's important. This is how all disposable classes in .NET are implemented and how all classes should implement `IDisposable`.

Your code should look like this:

```
using(Graphics g = new Graphics())
{
    SomeMethod(g)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) for Microsoft's recommendations on `IDisposable.Dispose` method.